# How do I install Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.WindowsForms?

Tags: c#, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get the following Microsoft sample running, using Visual Studio 2019:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cost-Management-Samples

When I do a build, I get the following three reference errors:

[image]

I was able to resolve the first error (for *Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory*) by searching for and installing the corresponding NuGet package here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/

However, I haven't been able to find the NuGet package containing the *Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.WindowsForms DLL*.

The DLL exists on my system; there are 6 copies, two of them from 2015 and four of them the most recent version.  However, they are in non-standard locations; for example, two of them are in the following tree:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\
    CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Extensions
```

Two are under the following tree:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Extensions\
```

And the two from 2015 are here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Packages\
    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.2.14.201151115\lib\net45
```

My questions: 

What is the story on this ActiveDirectory.WindowsForms.dll, which NuGet package does it come in, if any?

When faced with such a situation where you can't locate a NuGet package, do you manually copy the DLL in question into the application tree?

Comment: Can you clarify what solution you're trying to run? Is it `helloworld-dotnet` from master branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was a larger problem at play which I found out through the explanation below, provided [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/4316):

> 1. User Token provider is no longer supported beyond 2.28.x of ADAL. We decided to support User token provider for .NET 4.5.2 ONLY.
> 2. If you want to target .NET > 4.5.2 and beyond (e.g. .NET 4.6.1) we will support ADAL >= 3.14.x and anything >= ADAL 3.14.x does not
>      support user token provider.

When I had first opened the *helloworld-dotnet* project in Visual Studio 2019, the framework was set as 4.6.1, which was causing the problems with the wrong authentication model.

I downgraded the project to 4.5.2.  I also forced the ADAL NuGet package to load version 2.28.4 (dated 3/22/2017).  Afterwards, everything fell in place, as the missing DLL (i.e. *ActiveDirectory.WindowsForms.dll*) was supplied as part of the older version of the ADAL package.

**UPDATE:**


Encouraged by the answer from *tvdias* [here on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59129290/), I got the solution to work with .NET 4.6.1 as follows:

- Used version 2.28.4 of the *ADAL* NuGet package.
- Added *System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension* NuGet package (only a single version of this package exists: 5.2.3).

Here are the final contents of the packages folder:
[image]

Note: The *ARMClient.Authentication.dll* file was already in the folder.  The packages other than the two I mentioned above were installed as dependencies.

So, with the benefit of hindsight, here's a better recap of the problem: When I had first opened the *helloworld-dotnet* project in Visual Studio 2019, the framework was set as 4.6.1, which triggered an ADAL version more recent than 2.28.4 to be installed.  The features used in the code of the solution, such as invoking the WinForms dialog, are not present in the current ADAL version.  This created the problem.  That is, the authentication mode in the current ADAL version does not even require a login dialog, and therefore, a WinForms DLL is not required.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it working on VS 2019 and .net 4.6.1 by

1. installing ARM client (I've used chocolatey: `choco install armclient`),
2. removing the packages flagged with the attention sign on the image and
3. installing `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` version `2.28.0`.

Comment: Thanks for the information about running with 4.6.1, will try it out.

Comment: Any luck on this @Sabuncu?

Comment: PS: I don't understand what you mean by "the not found packages on the image".  Do you mean the missing references in the solution? Thanks.

Comment: @Sabuncu, I mean the packages flagged with the attention sign. Updated it on the answer.

Comment: Not to be nitpicking, but "image" is not a term used in .NET.  I see yellow triangles under References, for those external DLLs that the could not be located.  The NuGet packages show up arrows indicating updates are available.  Maybe chocolatey you use has the flags you mention.

Comment: @Sabuncu, the image I mean is the image you've added, and not the packages :) regarding the sign: https://www.google.com/search?q=attention+sign this sign has many different meanings, including when the dll couldn't be found.

Comment: What is the image I have added?  I truly don't understand.  There's no concept of an image in .NET.

Comment: The image you've included in your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7iHh.png).

Comment: OK, I am so embarrassed now! :) That image is from the list of references in the solution. (From where I access the internet, imgur - the image hosting site - is blocked by the government, and I have to make a special effort to use another browser that has a VPN that allows access to blocked sites. Sorry!)